# Mocking DbSet.Where(lambda) with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a problem when I try to make this test successful (passing):

```
public void FindeParkausweisByKennzeichen_kennzeichen_ReturnsAusweis()
{
    //Arrange
    var dbContextMockHelper = new DbContextMockHelper();
    PasovContext dbContextMock = dbContextMockHelper.GenerateDbContextMock();
    List<Ausweis> liste = dbContextMockHelper.GenerateDbSetAusweise();
    dbContextMock.Ausweise = dbContextMockHelper.GetQueryableMockDbSet(liste);
    var klasse = new AusweisRepository(dbContextMock);
    var parameter = "k-fz 4711";
    
    //Act
    var result = klasse.FindeParkausweisByKennzeichen(parameter);
    
    //Assert
    Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf<Ausweis>());
}
```

The `DbSet` is mocked using this method (of the `DbContextMockHelper` class):

```
public DbSet<T> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T : class
{
    var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();
    var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
    dbSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => sourceList.Add(s));
    dbSet.Setup(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => sourceList.Remove(s));
    return dbSet.Object;
}
```

Finally, the to be tested method looks like this:

```
public Ausweis FindeParkausweisByKennzeichen(string kennzeichen)
{
    return Db.Set<Ausweis>()
        .Include(x => x.Organisation)
        .Include(x => x.Ersteller)
        .Include(x => x.Inhaber)
        .Where(x => x.Kennzeichen == kennzeichen)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The method should return one `Ausweis` but it returns with `null`.

If I remove the `.Where` part the first element of the data generated in `dbContextMockHelper.GenerateDbSetAusweise` is returned.

What am I missing?

Can the `.Where` part be mocked? If so then how?

Comment: What is returned if the `Where` is applied? Can it be that there is no item where Kennzeichen equals "k-fz 4711". BTW: the comparison in the `Where` clause is case sensitive. This might also lead to a null result.

Comment: With the .Where it returns NULL. Both one of the data in the the mocked DbSet and the submitted parameter are the same (even in case), so there should be one "hit" with the where.

Answer (score 0):

Your SUT is accessing the db set via `Db.Set<Ausweis>()`, but I can't see where you have set up this method. I believe you've set up the db set property (`dbContextMock.Ausweise = dbContextMockHelper.GetQueryableMockDbSet(liste);`) but you'll need to set up the `Set<T>` method as well.

As an aside, `Where` is an extension method that will either create or execute a query against the queryable provider. You can't mock it directly, you have to mock the provider.